# count zeros before a different value by ID in r

Tags: r, count

I need to count zeros by ID in R, but I need them just the zeros before a different Value.
Here's a example of my data.

```
x<-tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,        ~Date, ~Value,
   1L, "01-01-2016",     0L,
   1L, "01-02-2016",     0L,
   1L, "01-03-2016",     0L,
   1L, "01-04-2016",     0L,
   1L, "01-05-2016",  1000L,
   1L, "01-06-2016",     0L,
   2L, "01-01-2016",     0L,
   2L, "01-02-2016",     0L,
   2L, "01-03-2016",  1500L,
   2L, "01-04-2016",     0L,
   2L, "01-05-2016",     0L,
   2L, "01-06-2016",     0L,
   3L, "01-01-2016",     0L,
   3L, "01-02-2016",  -300L,
   3L, "01-03-2016",     0L,
   3L, "01-04-2016",     0L,
   3L, "01-05-2016",   200L,
   3L, "01-06-2016",     0L
  )
x<-as.data.frame(x)

 head(x)
   #   ID       Date Value
   # 1  1 01-01-2016     0
   # 2  1 01-02-2016     0
   # 3  1 01-03-2016     0
   # 4  1 01-04-2016     0
   # 5  1 01-05-2016  1000
   # 6  1 01-06-2016     0
```

What I'm looking it's something like this

```
ID    1 2 3 
Count 4 2 1
```

Because there's 4 zeros before a different value in ID 1, 2 zeros in ID 2 and 1 zero in ID 3. Also, I'd like to save it in the dataframe as it follows:

```
new_x<-tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,        ~Date, ~Value, ~Count,
   1L, "01-01-2016",     0L,     4L,
   1L, "01-02-2016",     0L,     4L,
   1L, "01-03-2016",     0L,     4L,
   1L, "01-04-2016",     0L,     4L,
   1L, "01-05-2016",  1000L,     4L,
   1L, "01-06-2016",     0L,     4L,
   2L, "01-01-2016",     0L,     2L,
   2L, "01-02-2016",     0L,     2L,
   2L, "01-03-2016",  1500L,     2L,
   2L, "01-04-2016",     0L,     2L,
   2L, "01-05-2016",     0L,     2L,
   2L, "01-06-2016",     0L,     2L,
   3L, "01-01-2016",     0L,     1L,
   3L, "01-02-2016",  -300L,     1L,
   3L, "01-03-2016",     0L,     1L,
   3L, "01-04-2016",     0L,     1L,
   3L, "01-05-2016",   200L,     1L,
   3L, "01-06-2016",     0L,     1L
  )
```

Does anyone how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: are the values always on different days?

Comment: yes, it does not depend on the date

Comment: Maybe `aggregate(x$Value==0 ~ ID, x, function(y) match(FALSE, y)-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(cumsum(Value != 0) == 0, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = n) %>%
  add_column(ID = 'Count', .before = 1) %>%
  as.data.frame
```

Output:

```
     ID 1 2 3
1 Count 4 2 1
```

For saving as column:

```
x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Count = sum(cumsum(Value != 0) == 0, na.rm = TRUE))
```

There's of course also no need for packages:

```
transform(x, Count = ave(Value, ID, FUN = function(x) sum(cumsum(x != 0) == 0, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: It works, thank you! is there any way to add it as a column to the df?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Which `df`? You will need to provide an example.

Comment: I'd like to create a new column with the result of your answer, I edit the question with the example!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it using purrr's `detect_index`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Count = detect_index(Value, ~ .x != 0) - 1)
#> # A tibble: 18 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>       ID Date       Value Count
#>    <int> <chr>      <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1 01-01-2016     0     4
#>  2     1 01-02-2016     0     4
#>  3     1 01-03-2016     0     4
#>  4     1 01-04-2016     0     4
#>  5     1 01-05-2016  1000     4
#>  6     1 01-06-2016     0     4
#>  7     2 01-01-2016     0     2
#>  8     2 01-02-2016     0     2
#>  9     2 01-03-2016  1500     2
#> 10     2 01-04-2016     0     2
#> 11     2 01-05-2016     0     2
#> 12     2 01-06-2016     0     2
#> 13     3 01-01-2016     0     1
#> 14     3 01-02-2016  -300     1
#> 15     3 01-03-2016     0     1
#> 16     3 01-04-2016     0     1
#> 17     3 01-05-2016   200     1
#> 18     3 01-06-2016     0     1
```